# Auto-Refresh div content with static html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to reload html div tag in every 5 minutes which call .js file in it without refresh entire page.

```
<div id="pie">
  <script src="index.js">// reload in every 5 minutes
     </script>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to get the script to refresh without reloading the entire page, try using an XHR for asynchronous loading, and then -*shudder*- use the `eval` function to run your new javascript **only if you trust the content in the script** because the `eval` function can be badly misused by your client for XSS attacks.

Here is an example of a 5-minute interval in which the script is gathered and run each time (remember this will only work if your file is on the same website abiding by the CORS policy)

```js
setInterval(function () {

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
       eval(xhr.responseText); //ONLY IF YOU TRUST THE FILE
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", "index.js", true);
xhr.send();

}, 5 * 1000);
```

Check out this website for more information on XMLHttpRequests: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

They even have tips on how to avoid cached files
[image: W3Schools XHR example]

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/node%20js/Election/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https, chrome-untrusted.

Comment: That makes sense, local files don't obey CORS, CORS means your file needs to be on a website, so then what does your development environment look like?

Comment: can I use XAMP for it?

Comment: As long as you can get it on some form of "http" and not "file://" although if this is just for personal testing then you can launch your chrome browser by navigating to the folder in Program Files where chrome.exe is installed on your device, and then opening the command prompt and using `chrome.exe --disable-web-security` should allow your file without the CORS policy

Comment: For example, my Chrome installation is in `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` so I would open cmd in that folder then run the chrome executable with that extra parameter

Comment: Its working on XAMPP but this code load after 5 minutes at first run also

Comment: I don't understand why if your script is already in your HTML? You can always wrap the XHR in a function and then call that function before setting the interval to call the function every 5 mins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229548/discussion-between-developer-and-da-mahdi03).